# vba - Remove substring from each Array of Strings element

Tags: vba, excel

I am storing filenames from a folder into an array. I am then attempting to remove the ".xlsx" part of the string from the filenames, and print them to a spreadsheet. 
I am having difficulties removing the ".xlsx" substring from each array element. I am led to believe that the Replace function is the best for this, but haven't been successfull yet. The area of confusion is indicated by the `'HERE` comment

```
Sub Example()

    Dim FName As String
    'Array to store filenames.
    Dim arNames() As String
    Dim myCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    FName = Dir("G:\ExampleFolder\*.xls*")
    ' Run until there are no more filenames.
    Do Until FName = ""
        'Increment
        myCount = myCount + 1
        'Actively store filenames into an array.
        ReDim Preserve arNames(1 To myCount)
        arNames(myCount) = FName
        FName = Dir
    Loop

    'Print array details to sheet.
    For i = LBound(arNames) To UBound(arNames)
    Next i

    'Create a random excel sheet to print the file names.
    Set o = CreateObject("excel.application")
    ' Activate new excel spreadsheet.
    o.Visible = True
    o.Workbooks.Add
    'Edit string in array.

    'HERE
    Dim LResult As String
    'LResult = Replace(arNames, ".xlsx", "")

    o.sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:" & ConvertToLetter(i) & "1").Value = arNames

End Sub



    Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you are trying to pass variable `arNames` which is array of Strings as a first parameter of the function `Replace` that should be `String` (note the difference between array of strings and string).

You need to replace those lines of code:

```
Dim LResult As String
'LResult = Replace(arNames, ".xlsx", "")
```

with those one:

```
For i = LBound(arNames) To UBound(arNames)
    arNames(i) = Replace(arNames(i), ".xlsx", "")
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Next i` is in the wrong place?; I assume you want the text horizontally from `A1`, replace everything under `'Print array details to sheet.` with:

```
'// create an instance once;
Set o = CreateObject("excel.application")
o.Visible = True
o.Workbooks.Add

'// get the startcell
Dim startCell As Range
Set startCell = o.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1")

'// loop removing the extension and writing
For i = LBound(arNames) To UBound(arNames)
    startCell.Offset(0, i - 1).Value = Mid$(arNames(i), 1, InStrRev(arNames(i), "."))
Next
```